# What is .apply doing in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I am doing the Netflix tutorial on Reactive Programming and I came across this piece of code that I don't fully understand.

```
Array.prototype.mergeAll = function() {
    var results = [];

    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};
```

Why use `apply` in this line of code `results.push.apply(results, subArray);`?  Why not just use `results.push(subArray)`?  What is the difference in the code?

Comment: Looks like someone is not familiar with `concat`… `return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this)`

Comment: Wouldn't that make an array of arrays, and not just one big array?  So you would end up with exactly what you started with ?

Comment: No. `concat` takes multiple arrays as arguments - and that's just what we give it with `apply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results wouldn't be the same at all. You can test this for yourself:

```
results = [1, 2, 3];
subArray = [4, 5, 6];

results.push(subArray);

console.log("With push:", results); // With push: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]


results = [1, 2, 3]; // reset results

results.push.apply(results, subArray);

console.log("With apply:", results); // With apply: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`apply` accepts an array of arguments, and the elements of the array become individual arguments to the function.

This lets you invoke the function `push` with an arbitrary number of arguments, where each argument is added to the array. Simply calling `results.push(...)` would invoke the function with a *single* argument, which would be an array, resulting in the entire `subArray` being pushed onto `results` as one element.

In the above example, `results.push.apply(results, subArray)` is equivalent to calling `results.push(4, 5, 6)`, while `results.push(subArray)` simply invokes `results.push([4, 5, 6])`.

The net effect of using one over the other is that, given an input array containing sub-arrays...

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

... using `results.push` would produce an identical array, where each sub-array was pushed onto `results` as a single element:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Using `results.push.apply` would cause each element from each sub-array to be pushed onto `results` as its own element, resulting in the desired flattened array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
var results = [];

results.push.apply(results,[2,3,4])

results [2,3,4]
```

Example 2:

```
var results2 = [];

[].push.apply(results2,[2,3,4])

// results2 [2,3,4]
```

**results.push.apply** is identical to **[].push.apply**. Both of them represent array's push method.

the first parameter in apply() method : results / results2, representing the scope/this inside Array.prototype.push method.

Here is [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/apply-method-function-javascript) giving a good example, how the first parameter in apply() method works.

If you want to know, why the second parameter of apply() method is array of arguments. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions)'s example has good explanation.

Basically

```
[].push.apply(results2,[2,3,4])

// results2 [2, 3, 4]


result2.push(2,3,4)

// results2 [2, 3, 4]
```

The first method is equal to the second method